# Ionic http get not working on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing a simple android app using Ionic Framework where at some point I'm using `this.http.get('https://somedomain.com')`.

Testing locally with `ionic serve` everything works, but on device it fails to load.

On the debug log the message is `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` and I believe its because the protocol is being changed from `https://` to `intent://` and I don't know why.

My code is:

```
this.http.get('https://somedomain.com')
```

and the error is:

```
intent://www.somedomain.com/path/2345435#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.net…ps%3A%2F%2Fwww.somedomain.com%2Ftitle%2345435%3FpreventIntent%3Dtrue;end:1
GET intent://www.somedomain.com/title/2345435
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http  in controller just like for connection webservice  in ionic

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
      url:  'http://come.emx/et',
      params: {'name':'parameterValue' },
        //type:'JSON',
         headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
             }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 //success
                 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {                      
                 $ionicPopup.alert({
                 title:'error',
                //template:'From date'
                })
        });
```

Comment: I believe I'm already doing this in controller. The code is in `./myapp/src/pages/home.ts`. BTW, I'm using Ionic 3.